# Angular ng select required option

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect, angular2-form-validation

I cannot find out how to use the required option in ng-select.

I have tried this:

```
<ng-select
    #skills
    required
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && skills.invalid }" 
    [items]="options" 
    bindLabel="label" bindValue="value"
    [multiple]="true" placeholder="Select Skills" 
    [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.skills"                                       
    name="skills[]">
</ng-select>
<div *ngIf="f.submitted && skills.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="skills.errors.required">
       Skills are required
    </div>
</div>
```

but no luck there..

Answer (score 4):

There is no build-in `required attribute` in `ng-select`. I always validate it through `form` validation.
In angular2 or above you can use `ng-select` with `ngNativeValidate` directive for template driven form.

```
<form #registerUser="ngForm" ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">  

   <ng-select
    class="col-md-8 required"
    [items]="options" 
    bindLabel="label" 
    bindValue="value"
    [multiple]="true" 
    name="skills"
    placeholder="Select Skills" 
    [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.skills"                                       
    required>
</ng-select>
<div *ngIf="!registerUserData.skills" class="invalid-feedback">
    Skills are required
</div>

<button type='submit' [disabled]="!registerUser.valid" [isFormValid]="!registerUser.valid">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I am also using custom `style` to red mark field when `untouched` or `touched` and `invalid`. You can put it in global `scss` or `css` file to work as same all `component`.

SCSS:

```
ng-select.required.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    .ng-select-container{
        border-color: #dc3545;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 0 3px #fde6e8;
    }
}
ng-select.required.ng-invalid.ng-untouched {
    .ng-select-container{
        border-color: #dc3545;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 0 3px #fde6e8;
    }
}
```

> CSS:

```
ng-select.required.ng-invalid.ng-touched .ng-select-container{
 
    border-color: #dc3545;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 0 3px #fde6e8;
}
ng-select.required.ng-invalid.ng-untouched .ng-select-container {

    border-color: #dc3545;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 0 3px #fde6e8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, when you do use @Majedur Rahaman's answer, remember to set the `name` attribute on the `ng-select` input.

It cost me a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check on the value of `registerUserData.skills` if it is filled than show your `Skills are required` else, hide it.

That is to say:

```
<ng-select
    #skills
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && skills.invalid }" 
    [items]="options" 
    bindLabel="label" bindValue="value"
    [multiple]="true" placeholder="Select Skills" 
    [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.skills"                                       
    >
</ng-select>
    <div *ngIf="f.submitted && skills.invalid && !registerUserData.skills">
       Skills are required
    </div>
```

**NOTE:**

- I do not know what `f.submitted` and `skills.invalid` are, but **assuming that they're related to the submit button event**.
- You can achieve a better result using **`ReactiveForms`**.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved that issue like that:

In my ng-select I've used the aria-invalid attribute And in my css I used:

```css
:host ::ng-deep ng-select[aria-invalid="true"] .ng-select-container {
  border-color: var(--vz-form-invalid-color);
}
```

```html
<ng-select bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" [loading]="!docObs$" formControlName="deckOfCardsId" placeholder="Select a deck of cards..." [attr.aria-invalid]="
        submitted &&
        f['deckOfCardsId'].errors &&
        f['deckOfCardsId'].errors['required']
      " [items]="docObs$ | async">
</ng-select>
```