# How to enable a ng-select to be required so that a user have to select a option

Tags: angular, validation, angular7

I have an ng-select statement and want to ensure that an option in the drop-down list is selected before continuing if a user did not select an option a message should appear to tell the user please select an option.

I have tried the answer in the following link: [Angular ng select required option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53432744/angular-ng-select-required-option)

Here is the ng-select I m working with:

```
   <ng-select [items]="mentorSessions"
                       [multiple]="false"
                       [closeOnSelect]="true"
                       [searchable]="true"
                       bindLabel="name"
                       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                       [(ngModel)]="mentorToShareTo">
   </ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FormControl. First of all you need to add your ng-select inside a form, add to your form a formGroup and to the ng-select a formControlName.  Finally on form submit send form's data to the TS file:

```
 <form [formGroup]="myform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myform)">
   <ng-select formControlName="selector" [items]="mentorSessions"
                   [multiple]="false"
                   [closeOnSelect]="true"
                   [searchable]="true"
                   bindLabel="name"
                   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                   [(ngModel)]="mentorToShareTo">
```

In the TS file do the code below to create your form builder

```
myform: FormGroup;

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) { }


ngOnInit() {
     this.myform = this.formBuilder.group({
          selector: ['', Validators.required]
     });                                                                   
}
```

What I wrote above normally covers your needs. If you want to take the input of ng-select to your TS file then create an onSubmit function as below:

```
onSubmit(data) {
  //do whatever you want with input data
}
```

For further information please reply to me. =)

Import in your app module:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

In your component.ts

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. When I add the formControlName="selector" to my ng-select my whole page is turning blank. What could be causing this?

Comment: I hope you added all the needed code that I mention above. Also look at the edited post for the needed libraries. This is maybe what causes the problem

Comment: Was my answer helpful?? Please let me know!

Comment: Thank you the answer updated answer was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in `required attribute` in `ng-select`. I always validate it through `form` validation.
In angular2 or above you can use `ng-select` with `ngNativeValidate` directive for template driven form.

```
<form #registerUser="ngForm" ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">  

   <ng-select
    class="col-md-8 required"
    [items]="options" 
    bindLabel="label" 
    bindValue="value"
    [multiple]="true" 
    name="skills"
    placeholder="Select Skills" 
    [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.skills"                                       
    required>
</ng-select>
<div *ngIf="!registerUserData.skills" class="invalid-feedback">
    Skills are required
</div>

<button type='submit' [disabled]="!registerUser.valid" [isFormValid]="!registerUser.valid">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I am also using custom `style` to red mark field when `untouched` or `touched` and `invalid`. You can put it in global `scss` or `css` file to work as same all `component`.

SCSS:

```
ng-select.required.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    .ng-select-container{
        border-color: #dc3545;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 0 3px #fde6e8;
    }
}
ng-select.required.ng-invalid.ng-untouched {
    .ng-select-container{
        border-color: #dc3545;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 0 3px #fde6e8;
    }
}
```

> CSS:

```
ng-select.required.ng-invalid.ng-touched .ng-select-container{
 
    border-color: #dc3545;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 0 3px #fde6e8;
}
ng-select.required.ng-invalid.ng-untouched .ng-select-container {

    border-color: #dc3545;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 0 3px #fde6e8;
}
```

Hope it's helpful!